# Evaluate query as a string in row

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Say I have a table where each row is a query in a string representation

> 'select * from foo1'
>
> 'select * from foo2'
>
> 'select * from foo3'

Is it possible to evaluate all the queries at once?

Comment: Is this a Redshift question?

Comment: @denismo I'm using redshift after all

Comment: You cannot evaluate dynamic queries in Redshift. You have to construct a large query somewhow outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change QueryString and TableName in the code below to reflect your table info.  Nothing else needs to be changed.

```
DECLARE @Query varchar(50);  

DECLARE query_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT QueryString FROM TableName;

OPEN query_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM query_cursor
INTO @Query;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   EXEC (@Query);
   FETCH NEXT FROM query_cursor
   INTO @Query;
END

CLOSE query_cursor;
DEALLOCATE query_cursor;
```

Comment: Can I ask why you used a cursor here?

Comment: You need to loop through each row of the table and execute them individually.  Using a cursor will allow you to select the next row in the table and perform the needed function.

Comment: @MichaelDeluca Was hoping for something elegant of some sort, but It will do the job

Comment: The question was about Redshift